# The B$\ddot{\text{o}}$chner-Weitzenb$\ddot{\text{o}}$ck identity on 2-surface $\Sigma_r$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

**Reference: [this paper page 7](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5511).**

The B$\ddot{\text{o}}$chner-Weitzenb$\ddot{\text{o}}$ck identity applied on $\Sigma_r$

\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{2} \Delta |\nabla\phi|^2 =\ & |\nabla^2 \phi|^2 + \langle \nabla \Delta \phi , \nabla \phi \rangle + \text{Ric}(\nabla\phi,\nabla\phi) \tag{1}
 \\
 %
 %
 \ge\ & \frac{1}{2} (\Delta\phi)^2 + \langle \nabla \Delta \phi , \nabla\phi \rangle + K_{\Sigma_r}|\nabla\phi|^2 \tag{2}
 \\
 %
 %
 =\ & \frac{1}{2} (\Delta\phi)^2 + \langle \nabla \Delta \phi , \nabla\phi \rangle + \frac{4\pi}{|\Sigma_r|}|\nabla\phi|^2
\end{align}

Integrate over $\Sigma_r$ we get

\begin{align}
 - \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Sigma_r} (\Delta\phi)^2 d\sigma_r 
 \le\ &  - \frac{4\pi}{|\Sigma_r|} \int_{\Sigma} |\nabla\phi|^2 d\sigma_r \tag{3}
\end{align}

**My attempt:**

I want to prove (3).

\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Sigma_r} \Delta |\nabla\phi|^2 d\sigma_r \ge\ & \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Sigma_r} (\Delta\phi)^2 d\sigma_r + \int_{\Sigma_r} \langle \nabla \Delta \phi  , \nabla\phi \rangle d\sigma_r
 + \frac{4\pi}{|\Sigma_r|} \int_{\Sigma} |\nabla\phi|^2 d\sigma_r
 \\
 %
 %
 - \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Sigma_r} (\Delta\phi)^2 d\sigma_r 
 \ge\ &  - \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Sigma_r} \Delta |\nabla\phi|^2 d\sigma_r + \int_{\Sigma_r} \langle \nabla \Delta \phi  , \nabla\phi \rangle d\sigma_r
 + \frac{4\pi}{|\Sigma_r|} \int_{\Sigma} |\nabla\phi|^2 d\sigma_r
 \\
 %
 %
 \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Sigma_r} (\Delta\phi)^2 d\sigma_r 
 \le\ &  \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Sigma_r} \Delta |\nabla\phi|^2 d\sigma_r 
 - \int_{\Sigma_r} \langle \nabla \Delta \phi  , \nabla\phi \rangle d\sigma_r
 - \frac{4\pi}{|\Sigma_r|} \int_{\Sigma} |\nabla\phi|^2 d\sigma_r \tag{4}
\end{align}

It seems like

\begin{align}
    \int_{\Sigma_r} (\Delta\phi)^2 d\sigma_r = 
    \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Sigma_r} \Delta |\nabla\phi|^2 d\sigma_r 
 - \int_{\Sigma_r} \langle \nabla \Delta \phi  , \nabla\phi \rangle   d\sigma_r \tag{5}
\end{align}

But I do not know how to achieve (5).

Please help.

Comment: Is the surface $\Sigma_r$ closed surface in your context? If it is, then (3) is direct consequence of Divergence theorem. Since first term of RHS of (5) is zero and the equality is just from divergence theorem.

Comment: @H-H yes $\Sigma_r$ is closed surface. Ok thanks.

Comment: You are welcome